# How to execute a stored procedure and then rollback the changes at a later time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, rollback

I am executing a stored procedure against a database through a C# application. I would like to do computations after the stored procedure is executed and then after the computations are done, I'd like to roll back the database to its state prior to the stored procedure. Most of the examples I've seen on stack overflow only involve using a rollback in a catch block of a try/catch block in the event of an error, but that's different from what I'm doing.

I'm not sure if I should be saving the state of the database at some point, and then do a transaction roll back with that state, or should be attaching a transaction parameter to the `SqlCommand` instance of the stored procedure, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via transactions. Sample is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx Yes, it also uses catch block but you don't have to.

Alternatively you can use database snapshots if your edition of SQL Server supports them but they will roll back ALL CHANGES SINCE THE MOMENT SNAPSHOT WAS MADE - yours and any other user. Most likely this is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a WAITFOR DELAY in combination with a modified transaction isolation level. What this does is executes your code, makes the query wait for a set amount of time, then rolls back the transaction.  During that time you designate, you can have another session query from your table that received the modification (as long as you set the transaction level to read uncommitted) and you will be able to see the new value.  Here is a sample:

In one window of SSMS:

```
CREATE TABLE ##testtable (id INT);

BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT INTO ##testtable (id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3);

WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

In a second SSMS window, run this query during the 1 minute timeframe:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 

SELECT * 

FROM ##testtable
```

During the 1 minute that the other window is executing, you will see value in the temp table.  After one minute, the table will be blank.  This works for somewhat simple tasks, but if you are doing test upon data that already has a test change to it, just do a snapshot or a database restore.

Answer (score 0):

Standard disclaimer: That might not be a good thing to do. (Okay, that's done.)

You could do it most easily in your stored procedure using a [table variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx). You can

begin a transaction
modify your data
query the modified data
insert it into the table variable
roll back the transaction
select what's in the table variable

```
declare @myData table (someColumn int, someOtherColumn varchar(10))

begin transaction

begin try   
    [make your changes]

    insert into @myData
    select something, something something

    rollback transaction

    select * from @myData
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction
end catch
```

Rolling back your transaction won't affect what's in the table variable. I'd trust this more than counting on my application to roll back the transaction. Not that it wouldn't work, but I'd just trust this much more.

That being said, you could just create a `SqlTransaction` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), execute your SqlCommand using that transaction, query your data, and then roll back the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

On ORACLE database if you want to wait in your PL/SQL program (“sleep”) you may want to use the procedure “SLEEP” from the package “DBMS_LOCK“.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE execution(xVal NUMBER) IS
      BEGIN

          INSERT INTO TABLE_1 VALUES (xVal);

          DBMS_LOCK.Sleep (60);
          ROLLBACK;
       END execution
```

Comment: please add some explanation